# How to get function to save results to dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, selenium

I am doing some web scraping using selenium and am able to return a phone number and email but unable to append it to my dataframe.

I have tried running the function and it spits out the correct information and I have tried saving the results of the function to a variable, then putting it into the dataframe but it just won't save the way I am trying to get it to save

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Phone', 'EmailAddress'])

def phonenumber():
   for element in browser.find_elements_by_xpath('.//span[@class = "phone ng-binding ng-scope"]'):
       return(element.text)


def email():
   for element in browser.find_elements_by_xpath('.//span[@class = "email ng-scope"]'):
       return(element.text)

df = df.append({'Phone': phonenumber(), 'EmailAddress': email()}, ignore_index=True)
```

Right now, the code returns "none" in the dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append each `element` in the for loop into the respective empty lists for each function, return them from the functions and then use them to create the dataframe:

```
def phonenumber():  
    ph = []     
    for element in browser.find_elements_by_xpath('.//span[@class = "phone ng-binding ng-scope"]'):
         ph.append(element.text)
    return ph


def email():
    mail = []
    for element in browser.find_elements_by_xpath('.//span[@class = "email ng-scope"]'):
        mail.append(element.text)
    return mail

ph = phonenumber()
mail = email()
```

Now use the appended lists to create the dataframe. This is assuming that the length of the lists is equal.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Phone':ph, 'EmailAddress':mail})
```